# getting hardware information of all devices on the network

Tags: linux, networking, hardware, nmap

I was wondering if i can get a full hardware information about each device on the network? (preferred linux commands) with the nmap command I found the devices in my net, but only name, ip addresses and MAC. is it possible to get full hardware info like CPU info, RAM info(size & freq of each card), PCIe cards are connected, Hard Disks, etc..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at configuration management/provisioning tools such as [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [puppet](https://puppet.com/), [chef](https://www.chef.io/).

Ansible is probably the easiest to configure in your environment in order to fulfill the data collection task you have.

Once configured, the `setup` module may cover what you need (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/setup_module.html):

```
# Display facts from all hosts and store them indexed by I(hostname) at C(/tmp/facts).
# ansible all -m setup --tree /tmp/facts
```